# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

This is my node server:

```
var https = require('https'),
    http = require('http'),
    qs = require('querystring'),
    request = require('request'),
    username = 'user',
    password = 'pass',

colors = require('colors'),

port = 6969;

function onRequest(client_req, client_res) {
    var query = client_req.url.substring(1);

    console.log("proxying " + client_req.url);

    var options = {
        host: 'http://'+username + ':' + password + '@site.subs.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/api/v1/subs/?lang=it&format=html' + query,
        method: 'GET',
        gzip:true,
        headers: {
            accept: '*/*'
        }
    };

    var connector = https.request(options, function (res) {
        res.pipe(client_res, {end: true});//tell 'response' end=true
        console.log(res);
    });

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    client_res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    client_res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    client_res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    client_res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    client_req.pipe(connector, {end: true});

    console.log(connector);

}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(port);

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Im trying to authenticate in a basic auth by using the basic sintax " *host: 'http://'+username + ':' + password + '@site.subs.com'* " but i get this error: **Error: connect ECONNREFUSED** followed by ip and port.

what do i do wrong?

Comment: You already run the server before? if yes, kill the old process and try again.

Comment: Did you allowed permissions to the current port 443?

Comment: I'm guessing the site you're trying to hit requires https, and in the url you're using http.  Actually, you shouldn't have the protocol on their at all.  I've not tried HTTP Basic auth using the raw https module before, but `request` is a great little module that makest hat stuff easy.

Comment: @ami HOllander yes i've tried it before, with a url without authentication works perfectly.

Comment: @Paul i tried to remove the protocol but had the same result

Comment: ok i think i've solved it.
Paul was right, it was about the protocol, i was calling a http url but i set https with its relative port.